# User warning: The following module is missing from the file system: content

Tags: 7

I don't know why but I'm getting this PHP error in drupal log. I've reviewed drupal system table but there isn't a *content* module. The next part of the message is:

```
_drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1156 of ..public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

I'm using Drupal 7.65. Is there anyway I could trace it in order to search for the problem?

Comment: Since you mention that you have looked at the system table, I assume that you have read https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215 Please try the Drush command just to be 110 % sure.

Comment: Yes. I did it before posting this question. That is why this issue is so strange.

Comment: You are sure the Drush command acted on the right site/db (if you have several sites or multisite)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I also reviewed he table record by record. There isn't a record with content.